# Script with colors (tput) is BW when autostarted at boot

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have a small console script that uses tput to color some words. Works fine when manually started after login as root. But all color is gone when I autostart it via /etc/rc.local or from cron @reboot. How can I fix this..

Answer (score 2):

`tput` uses the `TERM` variable to see how to write color sequences.  `TERM` is probably not set (because it is not really *on* a terminal. You can fool it by setting `TERM` to an appropriate value, e.g.,

```
TERM=linux tput set af 3
```